# Making a master server in Photon Unity Network?

Tags: unity, networking, unity-networking, photon

I am trying to make a game that requires a dedicated server running 24/7 and I would like to use Photon Networking but can Photon Network handle/do a dedicated server setup?

The reason I ask is because every tutorial I watch/read is talking about client hosting and not server to client.

Another question I have is that if PUN can handle dedicated servers will I have to make separate applications, one for the server and one for the client? To me that seems to make the most sense.

The third question is that if I do have to make a server and client application how do I connect to my server application with my client application?

Does PUN provide a URL which I can connect to or is there something else that I have to do?

If you guys have any tutorials you could point me to working with PUN and dedicated servers that would be awesome and if you guys have any information you are willing to bestow upon me that would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes photon can handle it. Btw a master server(what you meant with running photon in a dedicaded server) is whole differen thing. Master Server is a dedicated server which you run on your own machine and you are all able to edit the photon way you want.

From what i understand you are trying to make a server(actually a photon room) which stays 24/7 online, no need for editing the photon itself. You can do it by disabling players to create a server and just make them join to your rooms. Create another application which you can create a server, it will be your masterclient. What you created isnt a server actually, its just a masterclient of a room. Buy a server to run your masterclient to make it run 24/7.

You can check out official photon docs to find out how to create a room and how to make players join it.

PS: All the rooms and lobbies are still running at Photon Cloud with this way.